# Ansible yaml to xml

Tags: xml, ansible, yaml

I am trying to create xml file with yaml playbook.
XML should looks like this:

```
<accessControl>
  <ipRanges>
    <ipRange>
      <ip>
        <int>00</int>
        <int>00</int>
        <int>00</int>
        <int>000</int>
      </ip>
      <mask>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>0</int>
      </mask>
    </ipRange>
    <null/>
  </ipRanges>
</accessControl>
```

I have no idea how to create ansible task providing multiple identical tags (< int >). I am looking for something loop like or there is another way?

Edit:
I.E I have XML like this:

```
<accessControl>
  <ipRanges>
    <ipRange>
    </ipRange>
    <null/>
  </ipRanges>
</accessControl>
```

And I need to add IP and MASK into  tag to achieve:

```
<accessControl>
  <ipRanges>
    <ipRange>
      <ip>
        <int>127</int>
        <int>0</int>
        <int>0</int>
        <int>1</int>
      </ip>
      <mask>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>0</int>
      </mask>
    </ipRange>
    <null/>
  </ipRanges>
</accessControl>
```

I can provide IP and Mask in list, dict, tuple - it does not matter.
For a sake of this question lets say it will be like this: ['127.0.0.1', '255.255.255.0']

Comment: This requirement is well suited for [templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/template_module.html) -- specifically a Jinja (`.j2`) file rendered in combination with the template module.

Comment: Where does the data come from? You want "to create XML file". What is the input?  Your question will be closed if you don't [edit] the question and provide [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the data

```yaml
ip: ['127.0.0.1', '255.255.255.0']
```

the template

```yaml
shell> cat test.xml.j2
<accessControl>
  <ipRanges>
    <ipRange>
      <ip>
{% for item in ip %}
{% if loop.index is odd %}
{% for i in item.split('.') %}
        <int>{{ i }}</int>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
      </ip>
      <mask>
{% for item in ip %}
{% if loop.index is even %}
{% for i in item.split('.') %}
        <int>{{ i }}</int>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
      </mask>
    </ipRange>
    <null/>
  </ipRanges>
</accessControl>
```

and the task

```yaml
    - template:
        src: test.xml.j2
        dest: test.xml
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat test.xml
<accessControl>
  <ipRanges>
    <ipRange>
      <ip>
        <int>127</int>
        <int>0</int>
        <int>0</int>
        <int>1</int>
      </ip>
      <mask>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>255</int>
        <int>0</int>
      </mask>
    </ipRange>
    <null/>
  </ipRanges>
</accessControl>
```

---

You can use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) instead of [even/odd](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) index testing

```yaml
      <ip>
{% for item in ip[0::2] %}
{% for i in item.split('.') %}
        <int>{{ i }}</int>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
      </ip>
      <mask>
{% for item in ip[1::2] %}
{% for i in item.split('.') %}
        <int>{{ i }}</int>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
      </mask>
```